# We should add a kebab tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I love making kebabs and think we should add a kebab tag. It would be beneficial to those who don't have the sufficient reputation if someone could put it in. All in flavour?

Answer (score 1):

Tags are added to questions; they're not simply created in isolation, since their sole purpose is to mark questions. The best way to ask for tag creation (should you not have sufficient rep) is to ask someone to add it to a specific question by suggesting the edit. I've interpreted this as such a request for your most recent question, chosen [kebab](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kebab) as the spelling for the name since it's the title of the Wikipedia article, and added the tag to your question.

Side note: since "kebab" is a fairly broad term, and the presence of skewers doesn't really change things *that* much from simply grilling/roasting without them, I am not entirely sure this tag will catch on and be useful, but it's worth a try.

Comment: If we prefer American English terms as mentioned in another tagging question, it should be kabob.  The Wiki article is British spelling.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ How universal is that? Kebab is the spelling I knew too, though I've seen lots of the variations. I got the impression it was more random than regional. I'm happy to synonymize/rename as necessary.

Comment: Looks like Random House (via dictionary.com) has "kabob" as the primary spelling, while American Heritage, Merriam-Webster and Collins have "kebab"?

Comment: I don't know--its just the only one I ever saw in non-British sources.  I am not sure it matters all that much.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ: At least here in Ontario, where we have a *lot* of immigrants from that region of the world, *kebab* and *kabob* are actually slightly different things. *Kebab* refers to Turkish and standard middle-eastern style and *Kabob* refers rather specifically to Afghani cuisine. Almost every restaurant with the spelling *kabob* is Afghan.

Comment: The real question is what kind of rice or bread to serve with them!

Comment: Jefromi, I don't think we should encourage people to create questions on meta about creating tags by going out and doing it for them. I'd just direct them to the [tag help page](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) instead. If the tag is useful, someone will add it, or they can suggest an edit or leave a comment on their question.

Comment: @Aaronut Okay, I just figured no need to make him jump through hoops here, since if he suggested the edit it'd have gotten approved anyway.

Comment: Understood, though this subject [has a long history on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146949/141911) and historically these types of questions have always been closed on meta.